# Existing OCR scripts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, neural-network, ocr

I have an idea for a CMS enhancement, to extract text information from images (for example, scanned documents), and want to know if there is already anything out there to help me along?

Basically, I want to know if there is an existing OCR script written in JavaScript that can extract sentences/words from an image (using `canvas`, for example).

I know there are some scripts that do relatively small tasks such as captcha-cracking, but I haven't yet come across a script for extracting full sentences.

Is there such a thing, or would I need to write it from scratch?

Comment: I *really* doubt you will be able to do this. OCR is not something you can code overnight. It is an immensely difficult concept to code for non-trivial cases (like certain CAPTCHAs). JavaScript isn't the best language for this either...

Comment: I want to do it in JavaScript because I don't want to impose any additional strain on the server. The current reason I'm doing this is that I have a book of written testimonials that I'm scanning and adding to a website, and I would like to be able to add the text in search-engine-readable fashion as well. Of course, I /could/ run it all through an OCR package before-hand, but I'm also thinking of future projects where I may want to just run OCR on an image from whatever computer I'm working from, whether it has OCR software installed or not.

Comment: Yes, OCR is difficult, and it would not be an overnight job, which is why I'm asking if it has already been done. As for JavaScript not being the right language... why? Is there something missing from JavaScript that somehow makes it unable to do this?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at http://ejohn.org/blog/ocr-and-neural-nets-in-javascript/

Comment: The link @James posted is probably the only thing talking about OCR in JS you'll find on the web. That being said, you could be the first to implement something like that. You can probably find a lot of general OCR papers and work from there. JavaScript is now (and is becoming more and more) powerful enough to do this kind of stuff. We should exploit it.

Comment: thanks @Xeon06 - I kind of got that impression. I'd already read Resig's post months ago, and was hoping there was work already built on this. I guess it's time to get planning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/selead/node-ocr. It's a CoffeeScript libray to access [ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](http://ocrsdk.com) service.

Comment: looks like the closest thing we'll come to a solution! I'd /prefer/ a pure JS solution, but it would probably be huge and slow. Thanks @corvus

Answer (score 4):

Antimatter15's [Ocrad.js is a possibility](http://antimatter15.github.io/ocrad.js/demo.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) module for node.js [available on github](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-tesseract).

Comment: I enhanced it and it runs now with tesseract 3.01 as well as allowing to hint the language and use a preprocessor: https://github.com/joscha/nodecr